# Create Computer(My Computer in windows XP) shortcut on desktop from CMD?

Tags: windows, command-line, icons, cmd

How I can create a shortcut from Computer(real shortcut with Manage option in right click) on desktop from CMD?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example:

- Create a blank text file somewhere. In my test, I used the root of C:\
- Open the text file, and paste in the following vbscript code:

```vb
Const MY_COMPUTER = &H11&
Dim Act, Desktop, Link, ObjF, ObjFItem, Shell
 Set Act = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
 Set Shell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
 Set ObjF = Shell.Namespace(MY_COMPUTER)
 Desktop = Act.SpecialFolders("Desktop")
 Set Link = Act.CreateShortcut(Desktop & "\Computer.lnk")
 Set ObjFItem = ObjF.Self
  Link.TargetPath = ObjFItem.Path
  Link.WindowStyle = 1
  Link.IconLocation = "Shell32.dll, 15"
  Link.Description = "Shortcut To My Computer"
  Link.WorkingDirectory = Desktop
  Link.Save
```

- Save the file with a `.vbs` extension.
- Run from the command line, for example:

`C:\Documents and Settings\bridge> c:\test.vbs` (presuming you called the file `test.vbs`).

- You can customise the shortcut by editing the file above, for example the description or name of the shortcut created.

Comment: Thanks, but this is a shortcut and I want to show real Computer on desktop with Manage option on right click.

Comment: @sma6871 That's not what your question says!

Comment: @sma6871 Do you actually need My Computer, or do you just want the manage option? The management console can be opened directly by running `compmgmt.msc` from the command line.

Comment: @sma6871 You might be able to do it with the registry, see [this link](http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/30393-show-my-computer-on-desktop-registry-entry/) - I'm not up for messing around with that though, it might go horribly wrong!